# UITableView Pagination willDisplay call again and again swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, pagination

I am trying to implement pagination in `UITableView` after searching this  question on  stackoverflow and google i got many method but facing same problem in all the solution, in  willDisplay last cell method calling  again and again so pagination does not work it load data in loop  before i move to last cell please guide me  self.isGettingMoreData is false when all data is fetched.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if !self.isGettingMoreData && indexPath.row >= (self.datasource.count - 1) {
            self.isGettingMoreData = true
             loadmore(pagenum)
        }
}
```

and i am using scrolview like this  but in this way i need to drag at the end to load more i don't want to like this way

```
func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {

        //Bottom Refresh

        if scrollView == table{

            if ((scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.frame.size.height) >= scrollView.contentSize.height)
            {


                if !isLoading{

                    isLoading = true  
                     loadmore()
```

Comment: since its tableView delegate method, it will be called for every cell that is about to display. So You need to execute your `loadmore` func for the last cell only. try to use  `indexPath.row == self.dataSource.count - 1)` instead.

Comment: i think there is no difference between your and my method

Comment: loadmore method call again and again before i got to last cell

Comment: How do you update your dataSource?

Comment: i am just appending data into data in datasource

Comment: is willdisplay(with loadmore(pagenum)) get call in starting when view controller loads or every time when you scroll?

Comment: loadmore method call again and again

Comment: i understand the problem now the problem is when more data loaded one time last cell is called i don't know why how to fix this

Comment: still looking for solutions

Comment: in `willDisplay` method, change condition to `if self.isLoading == false && indexPath.row == (self.dataSource.count - 1)`. Make sure you are setting `isLoading` `true/false` at the right time.

Comment: isLoading false when tableview.reload method run but still facing same condition

Answer (score 0):

To implement pagination in a table view or a collection view you can put your code in scrollViewDidScroll method. Here is a sample code that I use:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {        

    if moreResultsAvailable {
        if let lastVisibleIndexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems.last {
            if let dataCount = dataArray.count {
                let dif = abs(dataCount - lastVisibleIndexPath.row)

                if dif == 0 {
                     pageNo += 1
                     fetchMoreData()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: using this method i must need to drag the last cell which is not good i want that when ever i go to last cell it should load new data

Comment: @Jhony If you want whenever you go to last cell it should load new data, you must check if dif == 0 { fetchMoreData()  }, If you want fetch new data before you scroll to last cell you need to check if dif < 4 { fetchMoreData()  }

Comment: For indexPathsForVisibleItems, the documentation says: The value of this property is an unsorted array of NSIndexPath objects, each of which corresponds to a visible cell in the collection view. Which means .last item is  not always the last item. Which means your code only sometimes work.